# PDO get name of selected columns as object

Tags: object, pdo, fetch

How can I fetch selected data to an object and retrieve the selected columns name with PDO?
Now, I'm fetching to a Member object in a loop, and manually add each column to the object by accessing it from the "fetch array". Is there a way to automatically get the column names that's been seleced?

```
$sql = "SELECT member.name, member.email FROM member WHERE id = :id";
$param = array(':id' => $id);

$stmt = $this->m_db->select($sql, $param);

$ret = new MemberArray();

while ($f = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $member = new Member($f['name'], $f['email']);
    $ret->add($member);
}
return $ret;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [PDOStatement::bindColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) and [PDO::FETCH_OBJ](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)